# run a job after multiple dependent jobs completed in aws glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have multiple Glue jobs **J1**, **J2**, **J3** which are triggered via AWS Lamda and Lambda is triggered via the files coming on S3 buckets.

Sequence is below:-

> S3(Bucket B1)--file added--> L1(Lambda triggered)-->J1(Glue
>   Jobs)-->insert data T1 table( RedSfhift)
>
> S3(Bucket B2)--file added--> L2(Lambda triggered)-->J2(Glue
>   Jobs)-->insert data T2 table( RedSfhift)
>
> S3(Bucket B3)--file added--> L3(Lambda triggered)-->J3(Glue
>   Jobs)-->insert data T3 table( RedSfhift)

Now, After completing all those 3 jobs I want to trigger a separate Glue Job(**JFinal**), which will process the data from T1, T2 and T3 and does some calculation then insert in **TFinal** Table.

Now how we can trigger the job **JFinal**. The J1, J2, J3 jobs are independent and the execution sequence can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Step functions would be a good solution here. You have to configure your step machine where your 3 jobs can be run independently, still the `JFinal` will wait until all the other jobs are completed. Refer: [Step Functions Getting Started](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/getting-started/)